# CSS overlay with scrolling content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a content panel inside a fixed-position overlay to scroll vertically, but it does not scroll, it is forced into its container.

Can you spot the mistake?
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p7ra117/)

Only the green bottom should scroll the header should stay where it is.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #502074;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height: 100%;">
        <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%; background-color: yellow;">Top</div>
        <div style="height: 10000px; width: 100%; background-color: green; overflow: scroll;">Bottom</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid adding a container to your Bottom element by moving its height to an `::after` pseudo-element:

```
.bottom {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.bottom::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10000px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbbga989/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the maximum height of the container like this

```
max-height:100%;
```

and add the scroll property

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

And your code will look like this

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>

<body style="background-color: #502074;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height: 100%; max-height:100%; overflow-y:auto;">
        <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%; background-color: yellow;">Top</div>
        <div style="height: 10000px; width: 100%; background-color: green; overflow: scroll;">Bottom</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't seem to make a difference could you post an updated fiddle?

Comment: also, only the green bottom should scroll the header should stay where it is

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @driconmax, it was nearly what I need, worked it out now:

```
<body style="background-color: #502074;">
    <div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height: 100%; ">
        <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%; background-color: yellow;">Top</div>
        <div style="height:calc(100% - 80px);overflow: scroll;">
          <div style="height: 10000px;  width: 100%; background-color: green; ">Bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p7ra117/3/)